# Setting cookies in PHP with foreach and reading them in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, foreach

I'm attempting to set a cookie in PHP and read the cookie on a different page with JavaScript.
I'm not too sure about how to go about this because of the fact that I'm creating the cookies in a PHP foreach loop and I'd like to read all the cookies in JavaScript.

My cookie creation foreach loop:

```
function parseSearchedTerm($searchedTerm, $bearer_token){
    $decode = json_decode($searchedTerm, true);
    foreach($decode['statuses'] as $q){
        $_COOKIE['text'] = $q['text'];
        if($q['geo']['coordinates'] != null){
        $_COOKIE['geo0'] = $q['geo']['coordinates'][0];
        $_COOKIE['geo1'] = $q['geo']['coordinates'][1];
        }   
    }
    invalidate_bearer_token($bearer_token);
}
```

Comment: You are not setting cookies at all. You are simply setting values in the $_COOKIE super global. You need to use setcookie() Also each loop iteration simply overwrites the values, which is probably not what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Please give a read on writing cookies using PHP, over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_cookies.asp)

*Set Cookie* in PHP
Generic way = `setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);`
Example

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", $expire);
```

Read cookies from javascript, [read this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
Example

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}
```